# Почему не активна сортировка по столбцу?

Tags: php, yii2, yii

Реализую таблицу через Gridview и 2 нужных мне столбца не активируют сортировку, не понимаю, почему так.

Код виджета:

```
\yii\grid\GridView::widget([
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                'filterModel' => $searchModel,
                'columns' => [
                    [
                        'attribute' => 'id',
                        'options' => ['style' => 'width: 20px;'],
                    ],
                    [
                        'attribute' => 'count_days',
                        'value' => 'countDays',
                        'header' => 'Дни',
                        'enableSorting' => true
                    ],
                    [
                        'attribute' => 'count_orders',
                        'header' => 'Заявок',
                        'value' => 'countOrders',
                    ],
                    [
                        'attribute' => 'expire_date',
                        'value' => function ($model) {
                            /** @var \app\models\NewTours $model */
                            if (!$model->expire_date) {
                                return 'Не оплачено';
                            }
                            return date('d.m.Y', $model->expire_date);
                        }
                    ],
                ],
            ])
```

Код модели:

```
<?php

namespace app\components\administrator\models;


use app\models\NewTours;
use app\models\RequestsToursGuides;
use app\models\ToursPlan;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use yii\base\Model;

class ToursSearchAdmin extends NewTours
{
    public $is_active;
    public $author;
    public $count_days;
    public $count_orders;
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id', 'is_active', 'count_days', 'count_orders'], 'integer'],
            [['title', 'author'], 'string']
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function scenarios()
    {
        // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
        return Model::scenarios();
    }

    public function search($params)
    {
        $subQuery = ToursPlan::find()->select('tour_id, COUNT(tour_id) as count_plan')->groupBy('tour_id');
        $query = self::find();
        $query->leftJoin(['count_days' => $subQuery], 'count_days.tour_id = new_tours.id');
        $subQuery = RequestsToursGuides::find()->select('object_id, COUNT(object_id) as count_items')->where(['object_type' => 'tour'])->groupBy('object_id');
        $query->leftJoin(['count_orders' => $subQuery], 'count_orders.object_id = new_tours.id');

        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 30,
            ],
            'sort' => [
                'defaultOrder' => ['count_orders' => SORT_DESC],
                'attributes' => ['id', 'expire_date',
                    'count_days' => [
                        'asc' => [
                            'count_plan' => SORT_ASC
                        ],
                        'desc' => [
                            'count_plan' => SORT_DESC
                        ]
                    ],
                    'count_orders' => [
                        'asc' => [
                            'count_items' => SORT_ASC
                        ],
                        'desc' => [
                            'count_items' => SORT_DESC
                        ]
                    ],
                ]
            ]
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        // grid filtering conditions
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'id' => $this->id,
            'count_days' => $this->count_days,
            'count_orders' => $this->count_orders
        ]);

        if ($this->author) {
            $query->leftJoin('user_info', 'user_info.user_id = new_tours.user_id');
            $query->leftJoin('company_info', 'company_info.user_id = new_tours.user_id');
            $query->andWhere('company_info.name like "%'.$this->author.'%" OR concat(user_info.name," ",user_info.last_name) like "%'.$this->author.'%"');
        }

        if ($this->is_active == '0') {
            $query->andWhere('active = 0 or expire_date < '.time());
        }
        elseif ($this->is_active == '1') {
            $query->andWhere('active = 1 and expire_date > '.time());
        }

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like','title', $this->title]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

В итоге вижу следующую картину:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не понимаю, почему столбцы "Дни" и "Заявок" не активны для сортировки как столбец "Срок действия". Причем, если я в урле пропишу
?sort=-count_days сортировка применится как нужно. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?
Заранее благодарен всем отозвавшимся.

Comment: попробуйте вместо `header` указать `label` в параметрах колонки грида

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ можно легко получить подглядев в документацию `yii\grid\DataColumn` (после того как обнаружим, что в конфигурации проблемных колонок есть атрибут которого нет в других колонках - `header`), у класса есть свойство `label`, документация которого гласит:

```
@var string label to be displayed in the [[header|header cell]] and also to be used as the sorting link label when sorting is enabled for this column.
```

если пойдем дальше, в родительском классе `yii\grid\Column` найдем свойство `header`, документация которого гласит:

```
@var string the header cell content. Note that it will not be HTML-encoded.
```

Ошибка у вас в том, что для работы сортировки нужно указывать `label` вместо `header`